# Amazon DynamoDB - get logs for read/write operations with consumed read/write capacity for last two days

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to use aws api to get logs for read/write operations with consumed read/write capacity for last two days or previous day.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudwatch tracks the read and write cap units in the below metrics

> ConsumedReadCapacityUnits
>
> The number of read capacity units consumed over the specified time period, so you can track how much of your provisioned throughput is used. You can retrieve the total consumed read capacity for a table and all of its global secondary indexes, or for a particular global secondary index.
>
> ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits
>
> The number of write capacity units consumed over the specified time period, so you can track how much of your provisioned throughput is used. You can retrieve the total consumed write capacity for a table and all of its global secondary indexes, or for a particular global secondary index.

To view metrics (console)

Metrics are grouped first by the service namespace, and then by the various dimension combinations within each namespace.

Open the CloudWatch console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/.

In the navigation pane, choose Metrics.

Select the DynamoDB namespace.

To view metrics (CLI)

At a command prompt, use the following command:

```
aws cloudwatch list-metrics --namespace "AWS/DynamoDB"
```

You can also use the CLI to get the metrics for a given time period.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-statistics.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/metrics-dimensions.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can I use amazon api's for java or boto3 for python to get the data  from cloudwatch  also Can I use dynamostreams to get consumed read/write capacity units ?

Comment: You can use any of the aws sdk's to pull that data.  Streams are more about capturing the changes made in the Data http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html

Comment: so, I can't use streams to get consumed read/write capacity units for every operation?

Comment: If you want to compute the capacity for each operation here is the formula http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.html

Comment: Actually, I want to create an alert to my user if it's exceeds 80% of table limit throughput on read/write but this alert I want to be from my app not from cloudwatch. so the data i get from dynamodbstreams will contains consumed capacity for every operation?.

Comment: You can create alarms based on the cloud watch metrics

Comment: We want to get history of operations on dynamodb with consumed read/write capacity and compare it with max throughput capcity. I know cloudwatch can do it but we want to provide it as SAAS for our clients this possible?

Comment: Cloud metrics are retained CloudWatch launched extended retention of metrics in November 1, 2016. The feature enabled storage of all metrics for customers from the previous 14 days to 15 months. CloudWatch Metrics now supports the following three retention schedules:

1 minute datapoints are available for 15 days5 minute datapoints are available for 63 days1 hour datapoints are available for 455 days https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/faqs/

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try it. and I will mark your answer as the right answer once tested.

Comment: I download the consumed read/write capacity statistics I used sum like Note in this [Screen Shot](https://gyazo.com/97591bde0ec4a289447a8f255ed3383b). but I used another static which is maximum like **` # I used period = 60 mean 1 minute     max([sum/60, max_request]) > threshold`**  Note sum/60 to get avg requests per second Is this correct ?